# Show that $f(x,y) = (x,1+y)$ is not linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand why functions like df/dx and integral of x are linear functions but I dont understand the format of this question and how to set the problem up based on what's given:

[image]
In order to prove this is not liner I have to show that f(ax+y) does not equal af(x)+f(y). How would I set that up in this case?

Comment: If $f$ is linear, you have to show that whatever $a$ or $x,y$ you choose, one should have $f(ax+y) = af(x)+f(y)$. However, if you want to show that it is not linear, __a counter-example is enough__. It's like, if you want to prove that "not every woman is blonde" then you can just give a counter-example by saying "hey look! Angelina Jolie has black hair!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try to see if it satisfies $f(A+B) = f(A)+f(B)$.  Here, let:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
We get that:
$$f(A+B) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
but,
$$f(A)+f(B) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}\neq f(A+B)$$

The easiest way to see this is just that $f(0)\neq 0$, but you can use the linearity condition (as I showed above).

Comment: This is helpful for visualizing the problem better, thank you. Can you help me set up the problem to prove this for all x, y

Comment: When I compute f(ax+y) using just x and y themselves, it seems linear.. f(ax+y) = ax+1+y = f(ax) +f(y)= ax+1+y... That's where my confusion comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Linear functions always send the origin to itself. $f(0,0) = (0,0)$ must be true for $f$ to be linear.

Your example is in fact an *affine* function, which basically means a linear function translated from the origin. Yes, the terminology is not quite the easiest to picture. Functions that describe lines that do not go through the origin are affine, but not linear.

Comment: My question is how to set up the problem to PROVE that it is not linear. So I have to show that f(ax+y) does not = af(x)+f(y). How would I set that up in this case?

Comment: You can show it for any specific example.  You're trying to find a counterexample to the condition that $f(ax+b) = af(x)+f(y)$.  If you find ANY case where it doesn't hold, that's enough to show that it doesn't hold all the time, and thus $f$ isn't linear.

Comment: @TatianaFrank, compute f(ax+y).

Comment: @TatianaFrank you should know that a linear function must send 0 to 0. If you don't know that, prove it. Now show that this function does not send 0 to 0.

Comment: When I comput f(ax+y) using just x and y themselves, it seems linear..
f(ax+y) = ax+1+y = f(ax) +f(y)= ax+1+y...

Comment: @TatianaFrank you're ignoring my answer so I can't help you.